# Can't access my reddit installation

Tags: reddit

I install [Reddit Script](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/) on my server but I can't access my installation. I try to access `http://129.xxx.xx.xx` (my server IP address but is has a redirection to reddit.local and here looks to load for ever.

I install it using my automatic installer and after that I just populate the script with some data as per instruction provided in the bottom of the instruction document.

I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure the hostname you used (it sounds like `reddit.local`) to point to the correct place.  The easiest method to do this is via an entry in your `/etc/hosts`.

Does it work if you request from localhost on the server?

The install script is designed for testing (i.e. in a Vagrant VM), not production; if you're trying to set up a production website, you'll probably want to [follow the manual install guide](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/Install-guide).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. It's not the same with Automated install script ? They say on page provided by you "These instructions will guide you through the process of setting up a reddit clone for the first time. We also have an automated install script for Ubuntu Linux 14.04.". Not sure how to set it in /etc/hosts/ also not get your question. I'm pretty new on dedicate servers.

Comment: Well, I remember that already try to install it from that guideline but I had some problem at installation of that dependents, are a lot and also are not provided the instructions to install thats, and that can be pretty hard for a begginer.

Comment: Yes, reddit is a complicated system, and not optimized at all for single-server small-traffic setups.  If you want to run a reddit instance, you need to be prepared to dig deep into the code frequently to address issues.  I can point you towards [resources for editing your `/etc/hosts`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=modify+etc+hosts), but if you're struggling at that, it's unlikely you will have a pleasant experience trying to run a reddit instance.  What are you trying to do?  Do you want to submit patches to reddit?  Launch some sort of intranet site?  There's probably a better option for you.